# Working in Europe on Schengen Tourist Visa

Tags: schengen, work

What are the chances of getting caught and the fines if someone from India/Bangladesh found working in any European Country on a tourist Schengen Visa?

One of the person I have met is working there in such scenario. I am not sure how safe it is.

Anyone here tried this or can give some kind of advice on this?

Edit: By working here might be like Self Employment, like taking Guitar classes, teaching Mandarin to some students/adults in some hostel or park or something and taking only cash. Or any other service, which can be dealt in cash and have very limited audience and cash transactions only.

Comment: basically you're screwed.  this is europe, not the easy-going third-world you know!

Answer (score 1):

Europe's a big place, so I'm generalizing with a wide brush here, but if you work illegally, you're likely to get **exploited**, the chances of getting busted are **high**, and the consequences are **severe**.

First, if you're working illegally, *you have no rights*.  You can get paid less than minimum wage, not be paid what you were promised, be made to work illegal hours or in unsafe conditions etc, and because you're working illegally, there's nothing you can do (except quit).  So this alone is a gamble and quite potentially dangerous.

Second, surprise labor inspections of industries that often employ illegal workers (restaurants, construction etc) are common, and *the visas of workers are regularly checked*.  If you're caught working on a tourist visa, you can expect to be deported and blacklisted from returning to the EU.

Comment: this is applicable for almost every country. I have edited my question to be very specific now. I am not sure if it will change anything as you have explained.